# Como pasar una funcion con argumentos en una signal slot pyqt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

```
from archivo import funciones

class Main():

   def Ventana_nueva_op(self):
       #AKI CODIGO QUE CREA VENTANA CON UN BOTON NO LO COMPLICO

       self.ui.button.clicked.connect(funciones.cosas("cosas"))# esto no me lo permite pasar asi
       self.ui.button.clicked.connect(funciones.cosas)#solo lo puedo pasar asi sin argumentos activando la función a pelo
```

otro archivo:

```
class funciones():

    def cosas(self,cosa):
        self.cosa = cosa
        print(self.cosa)
```

La cuestión es como puedo activar una función que pasa argumentos con un evento de click de un botón el error que da cuando hago

```
self.ui.button.clicked.connect(funciones.cosas("cosas")
```

cosas

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea una instancia de la clase:

```
self.funciones = Funciones()
```

y llame al método pasando los parámetros cuando lo necesite:

```
self.funciones.cosas("cosas")
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


#from archivo import funciones
class Funciones():                                             # !F -> Funciones
    def cosas(self, cosa):
        self.cosa = cosa
        print(self.cosa)


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.button = QPushButton("Click me", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.Ventana_nueva_op)
        
        self.funciones = Funciones()                            # +++
        
    def Ventana_nueva_op(self):
#       #AKI CODIGO QUE CREA VENTANA CON UN BOTON NO LO COMPLICO
#       self.ui.button.clicked.connect(funciones.cosas("cosas")) # esto no me lo permite pasar asi
#       self.ui.button.clicked.connect(funciones.cosas) #solo lo puedo pasar asi sin argumentos activando la funcion a pelo

        self.funciones.cosas("cosas")                           # +++      
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> ... puse el argumento como algo mio para simplificar el problema , la cuestion es que los argumentos los recibiria de combosbox y spinbox de la propia ventana cuelgo ahora el codigo para ser mas preciso
>
> Decir como extra que soy incapaz de acceder al texto de la caja desde la funcion borrar sino eso ya lo arreglaria todo sin problemas :). Es lo que tienen los novatos jeje

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


#from archivo import funciones
class Funciones():                                             # !F -> Funciones
    def cosas(self, cosa):
        self.cosa = cosa
        print(self.cosa)

    def borrar_op(self, id):
        self.id = id
        print(self.id) 
        

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.current_text = 'Item 1'                               # + self.current_text 
        
        self.combobox = QComboBox(self)                            # + QComboBox
        self.combobox.addItems(['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4',] )
        self.combobox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.on_combobox_func)
        
        self.button = QPushButton("Click me", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.Ventana_nueva_op)
        
        self.funciones = Funciones()                               # +++
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.combobox)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        
    def Ventana_nueva_op(self):
        self.funciones.cosas(self.current_text)                    # + self.current_text    

    def on_combobox_func(self, text):
        self.current_text = text                                   # + self.current_text 
    
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta ,sin embargo, puse el argumento como algo mio para simplificar el problema , la cuestion es que los argumentos los recibiria de combosbox y spinbox de la propia ventana cuelgo ahora el codigo para ser mas preciso

Comment: Decir como extra que soy incapaz de acceder al texto de la caja desde la funcion borrar sino eso ya lo arreglaria todo sin problemas :). Es lo que tienen los novatos jeje

Comment: @AngelGarrido  ver actualización

Comment: Genial muchas gracias esto si funciona jeje no pense ke tuviera ke dar tantisimas vueltas para poner el codigo en modulos tenia otro echoa lo gocho pero queria hacer buenas practicas para sus posibles extensioenes.... gracias otra vez que enrollo. ya te puse la puntuacion que ahora  ya me acuerdo

Comment: @AngelGarrido   Si mi respuesta te ayudó, entonces no olvides marcarlo como correcto, Si no sabe cómo hacerlo, compruebe el https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido para quien tenga este mismo problema una solucion bastante elegante en el código , una manera alternativa de hacerlo bastante legible (apuntar que la solucion de arriba funciona también):
Aqui el codigo completo solucione el problema iniciando todas las ventanas en el constructor para poder acceder a todo no  se si eso es un problema de eficiencia pero el codigo se lee muy bien asi

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Funciones import *
from Ventana_principal import VentanaPrincipal
from Ventana_nueva_op import VentanaNuevaOperacion



class Main():
    def __init__(self):
       self.ejecutar = Funciones()

       self.interfazNuevaOperacion = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(interfazPrincipal)
       self.uiNuevaOp = VentanaNuevaOperacion()
       self.uiNuevaOp.setupUi(self.interfazNuevaOperacion)
       self.uiNuevaOp.aceptarNueva.clicked.connect(self.nuevaOp)
       self.uiNuevaOp.cancelarNueva.clicked.connect(self.interfazNuevaOperacion.close)
       self.uiNuevaOp.aceptarNueva.clicked.connect(self.interfazNuevaOperacion.close)

    def Ventana_nueva_op(self):
        self.interfazNuevaOperacion.show()

    def nuevaOp(self):

        self.lista = [None] * 2
        self.lista[0] = int(self.uiNuevaOp.spinBoxTendRecorrida.value())
        self.ejecutar.agregar_op(self.lista)

if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Crea la aplicacion
interfazPrincipal = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()  # Crea la ventana
ui = VentanaPrincipal()  # Accede al objeto que es toda la interfaz
ui.setupUi(interfazPrincipal)  # Carga la configuracion al padre mainwindow
interfazPrincipal.showMaximized()
interfazPrincipal.show()  # Muestra la ventana
ejecutar = Main()

ui.actionNueva_operacion.triggered.connect(ejecutar.Ventana_nueva_op)
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(ejecutar.Ventana_nueva_op)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

archivo externo llamado Ventana_nueva_op

```
class Funciones():
    def agregar_op(self,parametro):
        self.parametro = parametro #esto recoje el/los  atributos pasados
```